# If p is a prime and $a^2 \equiv 1$ mod p, prove that $a \equiv \pm 1$ mod p.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

If p is a prime and $a^2 \equiv 1$ mod p,  prove that $a \equiv \pm 1$ mod p.

I am having trouble proving this. I think I may have proved. I squared both sides because you the same rules as when you are in base 10 the only difference is that your answer stays in terms of mod m. My proof is as follows:

Let $p$ be prime and $a^2 \equiv 1$ mod p.

Then, 
     $a^2 \equiv 1$ mod p$\Leftrightarrow$
     $\sqrt{a^2 }\equiv \sqrt{1}) \Leftrightarrow a\equiv \pm1$

Comment: You somehow need to make use of the fact that $p$ is prime.  Take for alternate example the equivalence $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ where we learn $a$ could be *any* of $1,3,5,7$ and it is *not* true that $a\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$ as the only possibility.

Comment: Why does $\sqrt 1=\pm 1$?  Notice $4^2 \equiv 1\mod 15$ but $4\not \equiv \pm 1\mod 15$.  Why do non unit square roots exist when 15 isn't prime.  $\sqrt {1}\equiv 1,4,11,14\mod 15$.  4 square roots.  Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

$$(a-1)(a+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

If $a-1$ is not a multiple of $p$ (hence the index of $p$ is $0$ in  prime factoriation of $a-1$) and $a+1$ is not a multiple of $p$ (hence the index of $p$ is $0$ in  prime factoriation of $a+1$), then their product is not a multiple of $p$ since $p$ is a prime. We can see this from the prime factorization. In the prime factorization of $(a-1)(a+1)$, index of $p$ is $0$. Hence it is not divisible by $p$.

Hence $a-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ or $a+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't work.

For one thing, where are you using the fact that $p$ is prime?

Instead, express the congruence as a divisibility condition, work with that, and then convert back later . . .

\begin{align*}
&a^2 \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&p{\,\mid\,}(a^2-1)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&p{\,\mid\,}(a+1)(a-1)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&p{\,\mid\,}(a+1)\;\;\text{or}\;\;p{\,\mid\,}(a-1)\qquad
\text{[since $p$ is prime]}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a+1 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)\;\;\text{or}\;\;a-1 \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)\;\;\text{or}\;\;a \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a \equiv \pm 1\;(\text{mod}\;p)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Consider  the quotient ring $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

Since $p$ is prime, this is a field, and $a$ is a solution of the equation $x^2-1=0$. In a field, a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots, and we already have two obvious roots, $1$ and $-1$ (these are one and the same if $p=2$).